# PhpStorm Notify if Git branch behind Remote

Tags: git, phpstorm

Is it possible to set up Phpstorm to give a notification about remote branches being ahead of local?
I end up forgetting to Pull and then have to merge changes needlessly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not supported yet, please [vote for this feature request](http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-24057).